# Prove that a quadrilateral is convex

Tags: geometry

Given 4 points `A(Xa,Ya)`,`B(Xb,Yb)`,`C(Xc,Yc)`,`D(Xd,Yd)` in an euclidean plane, assuming that the quadrilateral $ABCD$ formed by the 4 points is convex, decide if a given point `M(Xi,Yi)` belongs to the convex cover of the quadrilateral.

How can I solve this ? I have searched eveywhere and I can't find a step by step solution.
Thanks.

Comment: The quadraliteral does not need to be convex: take for example $A=(0,0)$, $B=(10,0)$, $C=(1,1)$, $D=(0,10)$. My guess is that you have mis-worded the question in some manner.

Comment: The question is alright, I have to prove if the quadrilateral is convex and only if it is convex then I have to go further into seeing if a point belongs to the cover of the quadrilateral. If it isn't convex then I am not interested in that point.

Comment: Based on your response, I have reworded your question in the hopes of clarifying the meaning. If I have incorrectly reworded the question, feel free to reverse my changes.

Comment: Exactly what I meant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the following procedure: given two points $P = (X_p,Y_p)$ and $Q = (X_q,Y_q)$ which determine the line $\overline{PQ}$ in the $(x,y)$ plane, the following function $f_{PQ}(x,y)$ is zero on the line, positive on one side of that line, and negative on its other side:
$$f_{PQ}(x,y) = \frac{x-x_P}{x_Q-x_P} - \frac{y-y_P}{y_Q-y_P}
$$
Then given a third point $R$ not on the line $\overline{PQ}$, define the function $f_{PQR}(x,y)$ to equal either $f_{PQ}(x,y)$ if $f_{PQ}(x_R,y_R)$ is positive, or to equal $-f_{PQ}(x,y)$ if $f_{PQ}(x_R,y_R)$ is negative.

The point $M$ is in the quadrilateral if and only if none of the following four values is negative:
$$f_{ABC}(x_M,y_M), \,\,\,\, f_{BCD}(x_M,y_M),  \,\,\,\, f_{CDA}(x_M,y_M),  \,\,\,\, f_{DBA}(x_M,y_M)
$$